# How could session cookies get lost during OIDC redirection?

Tags: openid-connect, session-cookies, kerberos, okta

I have a java-based desktop app (with a java server) that's using the OIDC authorization code flow with Okta for authentication. It's working fine in several different instances, but a client has set up an on-premise server that's failing. I'm storing the 'state' parameter in a server-only cookie so I can check it against the state value in the authentication response. The problem is that state cookie is null when my app server receives the auth response.

I suspect it has something to do with the client's networking setup. I have limited information so I'm trying to figure out what questions to ask their IT, or troubleshooting steps to try. There are two details of their setup I'm suspicious of:

1. They have a proxy that's effecting most of their network traffic. It *does not* effect traffic with the app server, but it does apply to Okta URLs. (They haven't explained what this proxy is doing, but I found evidence of it in the network logs.)
2. They're using agentless desktop SSO with Kerberos.

I have the network logs from a user who tried to login (collected with chrome://net-export/). It seems like the final redirect back to our server doesn't have a source dependency on original request, so the app server doesn't know that it should resume the original HTTPSession on the server.

In the clients (broken) example, the source dependency points back to a redirect from Okta server related to Kerberos.
[image: Screenshot of chrome networking logs]

If I trace the dependencies back further, it hits this Okta URL...
[image: screenshot of chrome networking logs]

... and then dead-ends at new socket to that same Okta domain:
[image: screenshot of chrome networking logs]

In my working example, the final redirect's dependency points directly back to the original request to the app server.
[image: screenshot of chrome networking logs]
Upon receiving that original request, the server sets the state cookie:
[image]

I don't know if I'm interpreting these logs correctly, or *why* these dependency chains are so different, but it seems like the break is happening somewhere in the communication between Okta and Kerberos. Is there any way to confirm that outside of disabling agentless SSO?

I appreciate any help or insights into this.

Update: Adding details of the OIDC implementation.

Here's what happens when you hit the login button on the app:

1. The desktop client starts an HTTPListener listening a certain port to receive the final response asynchronously.
2. Open the system default browser to a URL on the app server that starts the auth request. <app server>/login/<idp>?port=<port number> (The port number is also stored as a cookie.)
3. Generate a state a PKCE challenge, store in cookies. Create the auth request and redirect to <idp endpoint>?scope=openid+email+offline_access+groups&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<app server path for redirection>&state=<state>
4. User completes authentication challenge.
5. Server receives the auth response. <redirect URL>?code=<auth code>&state=<state value>
6. Server picks up the state cookie to validate against the state param in the response. Then picks up the port cookie from step 2 and sends the authentication result back to the desktop client.

I'm happy to refactor to avoid cookies, but I'm not sure how to connect the state parameter value back to the original state value. Maybe that's overkill, and the server can just hold a set of valid states and verify that the returned param is somewhere in that set? (Or really, set of state-code verifier pairs.)

Answer (score 1):

Well cookies should only usually be returned to browser clients. Using cookies outside of the browser is non-standard and more likely to run into infrastructure problems. Eg, a proxy server or firewall might only return cookies if the request has an `origin` header. In some cases valid origins might also be whitelisted.

The `state` and `code_verifier` parameters in a desktop client are usually stored within the app, while login runs in the system browser. This is explained in [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252). Sometimes people try to use website solutions for native apps, but that usually works less well.

**PROPOSED UPDATES**

Here is some example code (in Node.js, which you would need to translate to Java) that shows the most typical way to implement a flow in a desktop app. The request state is just stored in memory and then compared to the response state in the response URL.

```js
export async function login(): Promise<string> {

    const port = getFreePort();
    const redirectUri = `http://127.0.0.1:${port}`;

    const state = generateRandomString();
    const codeVerifier = generateRandomString();
    const codeChallenge = generateHash(codeVerifier);
    const authorizationUrl = buildAuthorizationRequestUrl(redirectUri, state, codeChallenge);

    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {

        let server: Http.Server | null = null;
        const callback = async (request: Http.IncomingMessage, response: Http.ServerResponse) => {

            response.end();
            server.close();
            server = null;

            const authorizationResponseUrl = request.url!;
            processAuthorizationResponseUrl(authorizationResponseUrl, state, codeVerifier);
        }

        server = Http.createServer(callback);
        server.listen(port);
        openSystemBrowser(authorizationUrl);
    });
}
```

This may not properly explain the infrastructure problem you have, but it will remove the need for a server component or cookies to be involved in your OAuth flow. It is simpler and more standard, so hopefully also fixes your customer problem. More on desktop app general behavior in some [blog posts of mine](https://authguidance.com/desktop-apps-overview/).

Comment: Thanks, I added those details. I don't think the cookies are being saved/read from different jars, since this is working in several other environments. But I'm happy to avoid using cookies if that's possible.

Comment: Cool - I added some updates and example code to show the type of approach that is most commonly used for a desktop app.